# C# LINQ get max element in group by column of another collection

Tags: c#, linq, join, group-by

I have an collection of `students` and collection of `universities`. For each university i need to pick student with highest score. I want to group universities by name and select student that got highest score in that univesity. Like this:

```
Country | Name            | Student | Score
New York| NY University   | Bob     | 120
LA      | LA Univesity    | Tom     | 140
```

So far i got there

```
 return from university in Universities
                   join country in Countries on university.Id equals country.Id
                   orderby country.Name
                   group university by university.Name into g
                   select new
                   {
                       g.Key,
                       maxScore = g.Max(student => student.Score) <-- student.Score is only available in Students class
                   };
```

Problem is university only got access to students id i.e each `Universty` got only thos fields:

```
int Country.Id,
string Name,
int Student.Id
```

and problem is how do i get only 1 student with max score in that `g` group.

Student:

```
Id,
Name,
Score
```

Comment: What's the type of `student` here: `maxScore = g.Max(student => student.Score)`? It's not `Student`, is it?

Comment: no. in g.Max() i can only access to University fields(countryId, name, studentId)

Comment: So why have you named the variable `student` if it's type `University`? Name it something reasonable.

Comment: *"university only got access to students id and if i join students"*. Then the next step is obvious, is it not? You need access to `Student` objects and the only way to achieve that is to join, so join.

Comment: By the way, how exactly are New York and LA countries?

Comment: Are you saying that `University` has a `StudentId` property? Surely that's backwards, i.e. `Student` should have a `UniversityId`. It's a one-to-many relationship and the many side should have a foreign key to the primary key of the one side. One university has many students. You've got the other relationship the right way, i.e. one country has many universities.

Comment: idk about that. It was description of the task :D

Comment: What exactly are you joining here? Are these just collections? Are you using LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework or some other ORM?

Comment: Also, what framework are you targeting? If it's .NET 6 then you have a `MaxBy` method that will ultimately be useful. If it's anything earlier then you can implement your own method that does the same thing or use more complex LINQ code in the query.

Comment: it's just collections. List<Universities>; List<Students> etc. And i joined Student's but how i can get max student score in that group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

```cs
var countries = new List<Country>
{
    new Country { CountryId = 1, Name = "Country 1" },
    new Country { CountryId = 2, Name = "Country 2" }
};

var universities = new List<University>
{
    new University { UniversityId = 1, CountryId = 1, Name = "University 1" },
    new University { UniversityId = 2, CountryId = 1, Name = "University 2" },
    new University { UniversityId = 3, CountryId = 2, Name = "University 3" },
    new University { UniversityId = 4, CountryId = 2, Name = "University 4" }
};

var students = new List<Student>
{
    new Student { StudentId = 1, UniversityId = 1, Name = "Student 1", Score = 50 },
    new Student { StudentId = 2, UniversityId = 1, Name = "Student 2", Score = 100 },
    new Student { StudentId = 3, UniversityId = 2, Name = "Student 3", Score = 100 },
    new Student { StudentId = 4, UniversityId = 2, Name = "Student 4", Score = 50 },
    new Student { StudentId = 5, UniversityId = 3, Name = "Student 5", Score = 100 },
    new Student { StudentId = 6, UniversityId = 3, Name = "Student 6", Score = 50 },
    new Student { StudentId = 7, UniversityId = 4, Name = "Student 7", Score = 50 },
    new Student { StudentId = 8, UniversityId = 4, Name = "Student 8", Score = 100 }
};

var maxScoresByUniversity = from country in countries
                            join university in universities on country.CountryId equals university.CountryId
                            join student in students on university.UniversityId equals student.UniversityId
                            group new { country, university, student } by university.Name into g
                            let r = g.MaxBy(x => x.student.Score)
                            select new
                            {
                                Country = r.country.Name,
                                Name = r.university.Name,
                                Student = r.student.Name,
                                Score = r.student.Score
                            };

foreach (var score in maxScoresByUniversity)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{score.Country}, {score.Name}, {score.Student}, {score.Score}");
}
```

Note that it joins and groups all three collections. It then gets the record with the max `Score` from each group. This uses the `MaxBy` method that is only available in .NET 6 and later. If you're targeting an earlier framework, you'd need to implement that yourself or use more complex LINQ. I did ask that question in the comments for a reason.

Comment: Thank you, i did not know about `let` keyword. That's what i need

Answer (score 1):

Assume that your entity classes are as below:

```cs
public class University
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<University> Universities { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
    public int UniversityId { get; set; }
    
    public virtual University University { get; set; }
}
```

**Updated**

Without a relationship, you have to **join** between the entities.

To get the max score of the student by university you can work with `.OrderByDescending()` as:

```cs
var result = (from university in context.Universities
              join country in context.Countries on university.CountryId equals country.Id
              join student in context.Students on university.Id equals student.UniversityId
              orderby country.Name
              group new { university, student, country } by university.Id into g
              select new
              {
                  CountryName = g.First().country.Name,
                  UniversityName = g.First().university.Name,
                  Student = g.Select(x => x.student)
                      .OrderByDescending(x => x.Score)
                      .First()
                      .Name,
                  MaxScore = g.Select(x => x.student)
                      .OrderByDescending(x => x.Score)
                      .First()
                      .Score,
              }).ToList();
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kf8OaB)

Comment: entities don't have a relationship between, i.e University is `public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }`

Comment: Without the relationship, you need to join between the tables, but the concept would be the same, need to order by score DESC and get the first Student record.